# How to filter an array in ReactJs by comparing it with another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays in ReactJS as follows

```js
let document = [
  { text: 'Document 1', value: 'abcd' },
  { text: 'Document 2', value: 'efgh' }
]

let filterTypes = [{ value: 'abcd', id: 1 }]
```

How to generate the filtered array from this in ReactJS containing just one object with value abcd?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.some()` method inside `Array.prototype.filter()` method. Some method returns a Boolean value if at least one item in the array
passes the test by the given callback function.

```js
const doc = [
  { text: 'Document 1', value: 'abcd' },
  { text: 'Document 2', value: 'efgh' },
];

const filterTypes = [{ value: 'abcd', id: 1 }];

const ret = doc.filter((x) => filterTypes.some((y) => y.value === x.value));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const docArray = [
  { text: 'Document 1', value: 'abcd' },
  { text: 'Document 2', value: 'efgh' },
];

const filterTypes = [{ value: 'abcd', id: 1 }];


console.log('-----non-matched----');
const nonmatched = docArray.filter(doc => filterTypes.findIndex(filt=> filt.value === doc.value));
console.log(nonmatched);

console.log('------matched----');
const matched = docArray.filter(doc => filterTypes.findIndex(filt=> filt.value !== doc.value));
console.log(matched);
```